# How important is the exact name of an undergraduate degree?

Tags: degree

How important does one think the exact name of a degree is? Suppose a student had a BASc in Software Engineering (Bachelor of Applied Science, somewhat common in Canada) or a student with a BSE degree (Bachelor of Software Engineering, as awarded by, say Waterloo), would you perceive the students differently? Do you know of instances where this may have affected a student in a job search or in grad school admissions?

Comment: No and no, respectively.

Comment: In general, we try to be cautious about creating new tags - see [When should I create new tags?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). Having a large number of overly specific tags makes it harder to group questions, and makes it harder for new users to find appropriate tags for their question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The students would be perceived the same. When applying for a graduate program, you submit your transcripts. The classes you took, your letters of recommendation, and your grades would be more important than the name of your degree.